# Avoid 'unused warning' in for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, warnings

In Python, to create an array containing `x` random numbers, one can do:

```
import random
x = 10
[random.rand() for i in range(x)]
```

A variable `i` which is never being used, so this generates the warning

> Unused variable: i

in PyDev - and I assume in other IDE's as well (did not check).

Is there another Pythonesque way to achieve the same result without a warning?

Comment: The convention is to use `_` or `__` as the 'ignored' variable.

Comment: `[random.rand() for _ in range(x)]`

Comment: Or sometimes, the more explicit `dummy`. Either way, all IDEs allow customization of which variable name(s) are allowed to be unused. Especially as `_` is also the common alias for `gettext`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, how is it a duplicate? The questions are different for sure though answers are similar.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev: the goal of closing as a duplicate is to provide an answer to this question. The questions involved don't have to be perfectly the same.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yeah, but "ignoring warning in PyDev" is not even nearly the same as "what _ means in Python". If people have a problem with PyDev, they don't google "_ in Python", they google "warning in PyDev".

Comment: @VadimPushtaev: yes, and this post will thus redirect to that one. PyCharm recognises `_` as a placeholder.